# What are the differences between many-to-many relation and one-to-many relation?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem in logical design of a SQL Server database.

Still I can not distinct which relation has to be one-to-many and which one has to be many-to-many.
Someone told me if both entity tables are independent, they can have a many-to-many relation, else they will have one-to-many.

But now I am working on a project that collects personal information of the employees, in one part there is a table known as `JobStatus` which is for the personnel's current job. This table has a relationship with `Person` (table) that is many-to-many, of course there is a junction table between them.

I made this type of relation because one job position's name is assigned to several persons and with different performance.

For instance :

```
Person A ----->Operator
Person B------>Operator and so on...
```

And in other side there are some cases that a person has two Job position, I mean he is either a director and a teacher .

For instance :

```
Person C ------>Director & Teacher
```

So would you please guide me in this ambiguous logical mean?

Comment: and what's the challenge or the question?

Comment: I don't know is this correct or not?i mean having many to many relation between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you would recognize a many to many when either table can not have the PK from the other table as its foreign key

Taking a Student and Course table

- Student can take many courses
- Courses can belong to more than one Students

Putting a FK of course (CourseID) on student will restrict the Student to ONE course

Putting a FK of student (StudentID) on course will restrict the course to ONE student

To solve this, a third table StudentCourse will have the StudentID and the CourseID, therefore making either table independent.

That is Many to Many.

For one to many, that happens when you can easily put the ID of one table as the FK of the other.

In your case, Two Employees can be Operator at the same time and an Employee can be an Operator and Teacher - that design is MANY to MANY. You are right

Answer (score 2):

Based on the project you described, I would create three tables:  employeeTable, jobType, and jobAssignment.  Give each employee a unique id (a primary key) and give each job a unique id (primary key) and let the jobAssignment table be the glue that links the employeeTable with the jobAssignment table.  The jobAssignment table would have an index on the employeeID and jobID.

```
jobAssignment
---------------
employeeID (indexed)
jobID (indexed)


employeeTable
---------------
employeeID (primary key)
employeeName


jobType
---------------
jobID (primary key)
jobName
jobDescription
```

That way, you can keep track of the employees and their respective jobs in the jobAssignment table no matter how many job descriptions are assigned to each employee.

Comment: Example of SQL for who has a particular job based on Marc's table design: SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM employeeTable AS E RIGHT JOIN jobAssignment AS JA ON E.employeeID=JA.employeeID WHERE JA.jobID='Job you want'.